# Python web spider: How to solve captcha?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

The captcha is generated randomly. I get the link of captcha and download it. After that, I crawl the website using this captcha and headers which is also set correctly. However, an error shows up that the captcha is wrong! I have no idea how to solve this. It seems that when I get one captcha, it is changed. Can someone help me? Any help will be appreciated.

**My script**:

```
#coding=utf-8
import urllib
import urllib.request as urllib2
import sys
import http.cookiejar as cookielib
import time
import os
time=time.time()
cookiejar=cookielib.CookieJar()
urlopener=urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookiejar))
urllib2.install_opener(urlopener)

urlopener.addheaders.append(('Referer', 'http://www.jsgsj.gov.cn:58888/mini/netweb/SMLibrary.jsp'))
urlopener.addheaders.append(('Accept-Language', 'zh-CN'))
urlopener.addheaders.append(('Host', 'www.jsgsj.gov.cn:58888'))
urlopener.addheaders.append(('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MISE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1); Trident/5.0'))
urlopener.addheaders.append(('Connection', 'Keep-Alive'))

imgurl='http://www.jsgsj.gov.cn:58888/mini/netWebServlet.json?randImg=true&tmp='+str(time)
outfile=open(r'code.jpg', 'wb')
response=urllib2.Request(imgurl)
html=urlopener.open(response)
outfile.write(html.read())
outfile.close() 
authcode=raw_input('enter the code:')
url_company='http://www.jsgsj.gov.cn:58888/mini/netWebServlet.json?codeCheck=true'
data={'corpName':'苏州','yzm':authcode}
html=urlopener.open(urllib2.Request(url_company,urllib.urlencode(data)))
page=(html.read())
print ("html:",yzm, page)
```

Comment: Maybe, you should try this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/captcha-solver/0.0.3

Answer (score 0):

you should consider creating a session object.

When you post your authcode the session has changed and the chapta too.
I recommend using the requests module to do so (create a session object)

[Python Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)